# Trying to declare an array of a certain size in Scala

Tags: arrays, scala, scala-collections

```
var arr = Array[Int](arr_size)
println(arr_size + " " + arr.size)
```

`arr_size` is 30 but `arr.size` is 1? Why is this?

I am trying to declare an empty array that I can fill in later at designated indexes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Array[Int](arr_size)` creates an array with one element, `arr_size`, and is commonly written as `Array(arr_size)`, assuming `arr_size` type is `Int`.

Use this instead:

`Array.ofDim[Int](arr_size)`.

You could also use more functional approach and fill the array directly during initialization, e.g. by `Array.tabulate`.

Answer (score 4):

For creating an `Array[Int]` of a given size and initialize its values for instance to `0`, consider also these other API based approaches,

```
var arr = Array.fill(arr_size)(0)
```

and

```
var arr = Array.tabulate(arr_size)(_ => 0)
```

Note type `Int` of `0` determines the type of the `Array`. Yet a full declaration with type includes

```
Array.fill[Int](arr_size)(0)
Array.tabulate[Int](arr_size)(_ => 0)
```

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively you can do `new Array[Int](arr_size)`